# Binding inside the angular directive template with Isolate scope object

Tags: angularjs, datatable, angular-directive, angular-datatables

I am trying to add datatable in angular with directives. I am trying to add dt-options in the directive based the parameter passed in attributes and then setting the same to the partial html that is added to the element.

Problem 1 : I am unable to bind the dtoption (line no 34) object created to the datatable dt-options attribute inside the elem.append.

i have tried numerous options and nothing seems to work hence requesting the gurus to shed some knowledge.

```
"use strict";
angular.module('app.wizard').directive('table', function ( DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $rootScope, common, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/table-tpl.html',
    scope: {
        formname: '@formname',
        dtoptions: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
       var dtOption = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function (formName) {
            return $resource(url).query().$promise;
        })
       .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {                  
                $compile(angular.element(row).contents())(scope);
            })
            .withOption('headerCallback', function (header) {
                if (!scope.headerCompiled) {
                    scope.headerCompiled = true;
                    $compile(angular.element(header).contents())(scope);
                }
            })
             .withDOM("<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'l>r>" +
                   "t" +
                   "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs'i><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>")
               .withBootstrap()
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

        scope.dtoptions = dtOption;
        //not working
        elem.append('<table datatable dt-options="scope.dtoptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"></table>');
        //not working
        elem.append('<table datatable dt-options="{{scope.dtoptions}}" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"></table>');
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
});
```